# How to println(something) but doesn't print anything to the console

Tags: scala, comments, lexer, println

I have a requirement to println(something) but doesn't println anything and no new line printed, how can I do that in Scala?
What should 'something' above in println be so that it satisfies my requirement?

Comment: If you don't want a newline printed, don't call println, since it's precisely what it does. I don't understand your requirement.

Comment: You want to print() which doesn't actually print anything? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm having a language lexer assignment (lexer.scala) and I need to regconized and ignored the comments from the language but the main.scala forced to use println the regconized tokens, this is fixed by my teacher and the test case result is fixed by him too :( .

Comment: Explain this problem to your teacher instead of trying to find tricks to solve this.

Comment: also asked at https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-user/lfCsQh49O0k/discussion

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> Console.setOut(new java.io.PrintStream(new java.io.OutputStream() { def write(b: Int) {} }))

scala> println("test")

scala>
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer, could you give me some explanation please?

Comment: @MinhTrietPhamTran This is just another useless trick. It sets the standard output to a `PrintStream` that contains a custom subclass of `OutputStream`, in which the `write()` method is implemented to do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just relating *Florian Hars* reply from the google [scala-user mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/lfCsQh49O0k), which seems to better frame the point.

Let me restate your problem: you have an assignment where you need to ignore comments while parsing some code source file.

Actually you have a main definition to test the assignment which prints out the result of parsing the source file, and you want the `println` statement to ignore the parsed comments, so the teacher's condition will be met.

If this is the case, then the "correct" solution would not be to find a way to prevent `println` to print, but to modify the parser/lexer to avoid producing a parsed token when it encounters a comment.

The other way would just be a "trick" to get the assignment right by exploiting a particular "code configuration"...

Answer (score 0):

`println(...)` will always print a newline, no matter what argument you pass it. There is no way to prevent it from printing a newline.

Well... there's ofcourse the following trick, but it's not very practical.

```
class Magic {
  override def toString = throw new RuntimeException
}

// Will not print a newline, but will throw an exception
println(new Magic)

// So you'll need to catch it
try {
  println(new Magic)
} catch {
  case e: RuntimeException => // Ignore the exception
}

// Hey, we're here and no newline was printed!
```

Answer (score -2):

if you're still running the scala interpreter, you can exit it by entering the :quit command. Put this into a file named hello.scala:

```
println("Hello, world, from a script!")
```

then run:

> scala hello.scala

And you should get yet another greeting:

**Hello, world, from a script!**

Comment: sorry to say 
if you're still running the scala interpreter this will work